# theory scope and proof

Tags: proof-theory

I am looking for the proposition which states that a theory rules scope cannot defined all versions of a proposition because it is kind of creating a circle. 
Forgive my french.. And `approximation`.
Could anybody point me in the direction.. Preferably not the door.

**Edit** : *upon an old reading (more than 10 years ago, sorry I'm an old guy), I was trying to recall why a theory needed external rules to be complete or valid and couldn't hold all the terms to its own validation/invalidation. @Dave pointed me on the right track, even if I'd like to expand this concept to a more generic one, philosophically speaking.*

*Now, I really don't know (and humbly speaking) how to precise something that I don't know : I started the readings that @Dave gave me, maybe I will be more able to narrow. Until then, I will gladly submit to your enlightened advice.*

Comment: downvote without explanation is not use at all : at least tell me what I could do better. ;)

Comment: It would help to give some indication of your background level. Given what you've written, I don't know if you're asking about the basic philosophical principal (of which I don't know whether has a name) that axioms are needed to get anywhere, or whether you're talking about some issue related to Gödel's incompleteness theorems. Or something else . . .

Comment: Thanks. My background is a collective few readings.. So basic. But I do remember now (thanks to you) when I read about that, that Gödel was quoted. So I went to WIkipedia and found happiness in one of the consistency definition : for a set of rules inside a theory ~ "no rules combination could lead to prove p and non-p". In laymans terms, could you please explain why and point me to some more formal explanation ?

Comment: A good place to begin is [**Gödel's Proof**](https://archive.org/details/gdelsproof00nage) by Ernest Nagel and James R. Newman (1958). A bit more advanced is [**Gödel's Theorem**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1568812388) by Torkel Franzén (2005; [review](https://www.ams.org/notices/200703/rev-raatikainen.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks. If you put your comment in answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to begin is [**Gödel's Proof**](https://archive.org/details/gdelsproof00nage) by Ernest Nagel and James R. Newman (1958; freely available).

A bit more advanced is [**Gödel's Theorem**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812388) by Torkel Franzén (2005; [review](https://www.ams.org/notices/200703/rev-raatikainen.pdf)).

*(ADDED 9 DAYS LATER)* The following book gives a super-gentle introduction to this general topic. I don't know how I forgot about this book --- it was all the rage towards the end of my undergraduate studies (I remember reading about, and sometimes even overhearing discussions about, courses being based on it), it [won both the Pulitzer Prize for general non-fiction and the [USA] National Book Award for Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach), and it launched the career of Hofstadter as one of the few mathematicians/physicists (his Ph.D. was in physics) whose celebrity has reached the general public.

[**Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465026567) by Douglas R. Hofstadter (originally published in 1979)